# Could Thangorodrim be used to destroy the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-silmarillion

What happened to Thangorodrim's three volcanic peaks? I know Ancalagon fell on the fortess, but the actual mountain must still exist.

Could the fellowship have travelled to Thangorodrim and thrown the ring in there, as the power of Morgoth was still felt? Apart from distance, what prevented them from doing this? Also, after they got past Arnor, they could fly eagles all the way there.

Comment: Seriously, how can you remember Ancalagon and don't get that almost whole Beleriand and especially Thangorodrim sank into the sea?

Comment: I thought it was just the fort that sank. I didn't think the mountain sank.

Comment: Also, the blue mountains survived, and as the three peaks of thangorodrim were higher than those, I figured they still existed. Also, if it was underwater, could Ulmo not help them?

Comment: What fort? Like whole country sank - it would be nonsense if only mountains really worth destroying still stood

Comment: I guess thats true, but then how did the blue mountains survive? Also, was it the mountains worth destroying or the fort?

Comment: Oh great. I spent 5 hours searching google before asking this question (really) and only now I find https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9843/could-the-one-ring-be-destroyed-in-any-manner-besides-mount-doom?rq=1

Comment: The Blue Mountains 'survived' (and even then not entirely, the Dwarven cities of Nogrod and Belegost were lost) because they were far enough to the east, not because of how high they were.

Comment: @AdityaGoturu - Yup. Dupe.

Comment: Would it have mattered even if they were still around? The Ring was forged in Mount Doom; it wasn't just lava that was needed to destroy it, but the place itself.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. Thangorodrim itself was destroyed at the end of the First Age during the War of Wrath when the dragon Ancalagon the Black fell after he was slain. Thangorodrim and its volcanic peaks were unavailable to the Fellowship because they no longer existed.

Comment: You're mixing War of Wrath with Fall of Numenor :(

Comment: Apologies. Corrected for clarity.

Comment: Beleriand was sunk at the end of the first age, long before the cataclysm which destroyed Numenor and made the world round.